# Init with default vs convenience initialiser

Tags: swift

Is there any difference between init with default value vs calling convenience initialiser ? I try to figure out when should I use convenience instead of init with default.

```
class Food
 {
    var name :String

    init(name : String = "Unknow")
    {
        self.name = name
    }
 }
```

And this :

```
 class Food
 {
    var name :String

    init(name : String)
    {
        self.name = name
    }

    convenience init()
    {
        self.init(name : "Unkow")
    }
 }
```

Comment: Interesting question... I think convenience inits matter when you're subclassing, but has no difference in your example.

When subclassing, there are rules in how inheritance works with your designated and convenience initializers.

Answer (score 1):

Convenience initializer is easier for users of the class than a designated initializer with a default value because Xcode lists the two initializers by autocompletion.

**Autocompletion for a designated initializer with a default value:**

[image: Screenshot with a default value]

**Autocompletion for a designated initializer and convenience initializer:**

[image: Screenshot with a convenience initializer]

The screenshots are taken with Xcode 6.2. Unless Xcode supports autocompletion for default values, the convenience initializer is easier for the users, especially if you design a framework for people.

A disadvantage of a convenience initializer is, as Kelvin mentioned in his comment, you cannot use the convenience initializer from the subclass initializer.

Comment: Ok but It's only IDE (Xcode)  point of view. What about real advantage/disadvantage?

Comment: It's a general topic about ["Overload vs Default Values"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/152878/overload-or-optional-parameters) where some other languages use "optional parameter" as the term instead of "default values". (It's different from Swift term "optional", which means "nilable".) Swift specific difference on the initializers is subclassing as Kelvin mentioned.